# React useContext & Typescript: Not an Array Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, use-context

I have created the following context using React createContext:

```
import { useBoolean } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { createContext, FC } from "react"

type useBooleanReturn = ReturnType<typeof useBoolean>

export const MobileContext = createContext<
  [show: useBooleanReturn[0], setShow: useBooleanReturn[1]] | undefined
>(undefined)

// --- PROVIDER
const MobileProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useBoolean(false)

  return (
    <MobileContext.Provider value={[show, setShow]}>
      {children}
    </MobileContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default MobileProvider
```

As far as I can tell, this works as it should (at least I am not getting any typescript errors).

I now want to "consume" that context as follows:

```
import * as React from "react"

import MobileProvider, { MobileContext } from "./context.mobile"

const Mobile = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useContext(MobileContext)
  ...
}

export default Mobile
```

It is here that I get some typescript errors -- in particular, `[show, setShow]` is underlined with the red squiggly line and the following message:

```
Type '[
  show: boolean, 
  setShow: { 
    readonly on: () => void; 
    readonly off: () => void; 
    readonly toggle: () => void; 
    }
  ] | undefined' is not an array type.ts(2461)
```

I don't understand why this is not an array type or how to fix this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this

```
const [show, setShow] = React.useContext(MobileContext) ?? []
```

Only thing here is that `show` and `setShow` may be undefined. You can actually set default values for these if you want:

```
const [
  show = false,
  setShow = () => {},
] = React.useContext(MobileContext) ?? []
```

Though, setting the default value could mess up the type of `show` and `setShow`, for example you could set `show = 1`. So, you know...use responsibly.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const MobileContext = createContext<
  [show: useBooleanReturn[0], setShow: useBooleanReturn[1]] | undefined
>(undefined)
```

You've specified that while the value *might* be an array, it might also be `undefined`. If that's correct, then you will need to check for undefined before interacting with it as though it's an array:

```
const Mobile = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(MobileContext);
  if (value) {
    const [show, setShow] = value;
    // do something with show and setShow
  }
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't want `undefined` to be a possibility, then update the initialization of the context:

```
export const MobileContext = createContext<
  [show: useBooleanReturn[0], setShow: useBooleanReturn[1]]
>([false, () => {}])
```

Comment: I don't want undefined to be a possibility, I only added it because React Context requires a default value.  With that said, when I try your solution, I get a different error for `() => {}`.  Namely: `Type '() => void' is missing the following properties from type '{ readonly on: () => void; readonly off: () => void; readonly toggle: () => void; }': on, off, toggle`.  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You'll need to fill in a default value that matches the type `useBooleanReturn[1]`. I took a guess what that might be and did an empty function, but apparently that doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply saying it can be undefined, and if it's undefined then it cannot be destructured in that way.

It's pretty easy to see that this will throw an error:
const [show, setShow] = undefined;

So either check if the value returned from the useContext is undefined, or initialize it with dummy data.